# Выполняется определенный код при завершении команды через ctrl + c

Tags: python, python-3.x

Какие есть способы реализации данной идеи, кроме как поместить весь код в

```
try:
 обычный код
except KeyboardInterrupt:
 код при завершении програмы через ctrl + c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys, contextlib

def main(a) -> bool:
    print('обычный код %s' % a)
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
    raise ZeroDivisionError('err')
    return True

def excepthook(*args):
    la = len(args)
    if la == 3:
        (exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb) = args
    elif la == 1:
        (exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb) = (type(args[0]), args[0], args[0].__traceback__)
    elif not la:
        (exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb) = sys.exc_info()
    else:
        raise AssertionError(args)
    if exc_type == KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('код при завершении програмы через ctrl + c')
        raise
    else:
        raise exc_type(exc_val).with_traceback(exc_tb)

def test():
    try: raise UserWarning('ex')
    except Exception as e:
        try: excepthook(e)
        except UserWarning:
            try: excepthook()
            except UserWarning:
                try: excepthook(e, e)
                except AssertionError: print('ok')
                else: print('-1')
            else: print('-2')
        else: print('-3')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    sys.excepthook = excepthook
    # with contextlib.suppress(UserWarning, KeyboardInterrupt):
    main(1)
    # b = False
    # with contextlib.suppress(UserWarning, KeyboardInterrupt):
    #     b = main(2)
    # if not b:
    #     sys.exit()
    print('-')
```